# UIButton modifying titlelabel seems to change its frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Something strange is happening. Basically, I am trying to recreate the messaging app. So when I am trying to get the Send button to change from Grey to blue when the user has typed in at least 1 character.

The problem comes when I am trying to change titleLabel, the button will disappear. Later I found out it reverts back to the old position (when the keyboard it not shown).

Why does it do this? If I do not modify the titleLabel everything works as usual. However, if I do, the UIButton goes back to the original location. If you need any sample code let me know, but I am not sure what to put on here as it's just `[self.button.titleLabel setTextColor: [UIColor blueColor];` in the `UITextViewdidChange` but it's acting strange.

Thanks!
Alan

Comment: Try using: `[self.button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: @Firo Same problem. :|

Comment: Strange what you are describing, does just setting `self.button.frame` to where it needs to be after that line fix that bug?

Comment: @groovyCarrot yes it does. I wanted to know why it did this though as now I have to set the button frame when I shouldn't have to... I am wondering if it has something to do with new iOS7 or xCode 5.0

Comment: Sounds like it is probably a bug with iOS 7, I'm staying on iOS 6 myself until they've worked out the bugs and found a jailbreak exploit

Answer (score 1):

You might be fighting against auto-layout. I saw similar behavior, and someone answered my question here: [Why does UIButton resize when I access titleLabel property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22264731/why-does-uibutton-resize-when-i-access-titlelabel-property). Basically, I was suggested to forego auto-layout completely or *only* use auto-layout (never set frames programmatically).

Answer (score 1):

Well as mentioned here by others, you might be "fighting" with auto-layout. You do not have to ditch auto-layout, you could just bind the `NSLayoutConstraint` to an `IBOutlet` property, and update the constraint. If you do not have a constraint, then one is created automatically for you - you should create one manually and attach it. If it is created in code, the find it by code and save a reference to it.

You could also go back to the simpler AutoResizing, which was there before auto-layout (and is *not* deprecated, yet).